# How should I start an Apache server with mysql if localhost is already being used by Abyss Web Server(set up for php)?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, lan, abyss

I have this `PHP` script:

```
<?php
  $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'whatevermypasswordis', 'MySQL80')
  or
  die(mysqli_connect_error());
  mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf-8');
?>
```

`mysqli_connect()` does not connect properly to the `SQL` server.

I started with the script and ran it without the server. Then I installed the `MySQL` server using the `MySQL` installer and it did not want to connect.

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Note that I am running Abyss Web Server on port 80 on a LAN router to make a 'local webpage' that only people that have access to my wifi router can see this webpage.

Now I am using `XAMPP` to run a server, following the instructions on [this page](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-mysql-database-localhost/). I cannot start the Apache server because the abyssws.exe(Abyss Web Server) app is already using it.

Comment: did you add your port in connection ? port=your_mySql_port; mostly 3306 or 7 or 8 on default

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)